# View osgi bundles' dependencies?

Tags: osgi, dependencies, bundle

I am looking for a tool in Eclipse that I can view graphically all osgi bundles' dependencies. Anyone has any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2):

The STAN bundle and project dependency views are free add-ons. Here's a sample dependency graph: http://stan4j.com/images/stories/misc/plugin-deps.png

Quick feature list:

- horizontal, vertical, narrow layout options
- node markers +/- indicate outgoing/incoming dependencies currently not shown
- double-clicking a node adds outgoing dependencies
- double-clicking a node while holding the control key adds incoming dependencies not shown
- edge labels indicate "requires-bundle" and/or "imports-packages"
- supports drag'n drop from the project/package explorer

Visit http://stan4j.com for further information and download/install instructions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Plug-in" dependencies viewer in the Plug-in development perspective, is that what you are looking for?

Also see here:

http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/galileo-cool-views-to-control-plug-ins-ide/

Answer (score 1):

Found one. STAN tool is a good one (http://stan4j.com/advanced/acyclic-dependencies-principle.html). Although this is a commercial tool, it still has the free version that can analyze the structure of maximum 500 classes and have no limit with bundles and projects. This is more than what I need.

Answer (score 1):

There's tool from Eclipse PDE incubator called [Dependency Visualization](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/dependency-visualization/). Despite it's in incubating phase and seems a little bit abandoned, it doest the job very well for me.

1. Add new software site http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/pde/incubator/visualization/site
2. Install a feature
3. After restart, open Window / Show view / Graph plug-in dependencies under PDE category