# OSGi dependencies visualization

Tags: java, osgi, visualization

March 2016.
To analyze huge OSGi project with 100 bundles I would like to use visual tool (or some console or file output) to see all dependencies and interconnections between bundles (not classes)

What I found so far

- [How to analize/visualize OSGi, maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198176/how-to-analize-visualize-osgi-maven-dependencies) -> Is actually for Eclipse plugins only
  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-dependencyvisualization/index.html
- [How can I visualize jar (not plugin) dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972087/how-can-i-visualize-jar-not-plugin-dependencies) -> is for class dependencies
- [View osgi bundles' dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762939/view-osgi-bundles-dependencies) -> is 6 year old and was asking for Eclipse tools, while I am good with any that would give actionable upon results.

Answer (score 3):

XRay shows service dependencies. For a really good OSGi applications that is service oriented this should be all the relevant information you want to know.

OSGi enRoute makes it rather nice to play with this. Follow the [quick start tutorial](https://v2archive.enroute.osgi.org/qs/050-start.html) and you will run into XRay at the [application section](https://v2archive.enroute.osgi.org/qs/300-application.html).

Comment: I'm getting a 404 from the links. Is there an updated URL for these resources?

Comment: Links updated but the OSGi archived the site 3 years ago and is unfortunately no longer maintained. It was one of the few places to get into OSGi easily